# Unable to verify Ubuntu 21.04 ISO

Tags: iso

ubuntu 21.04 download verification failure. trying to verify download with command: `ubundu 21.04$ echo "fa95fb748b34d470a7cfa5e3c1c8fa1163e2dc340cd5a60f7ece9dc963ecdf88 *ubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso" | shasum -a 256 --check`. It says run  this command in your terminal in the directory the iso. Is iso files are part of this download? because when I run command in the download folder, I get failure message below:

```bsh
me@me:~/Downloads/ubundu 21.04$ echo "fa95fb748b34d470a7cfa5e3c1c8fa1163e2dc340cd5a60f7ece9dc963ecdf88 *ubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso" | shasum -a 256 --check
shasum: ubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso: 
ubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso: FAILED open or read
shasum: WARNING: 1 listed file could not be read
```

If ISO files not a part of ubuntu 21.04 download, where do i get them? and do i have to save then under the same /Downloads/ubundu 21.04 directory?
After download, how do I install ubuntu 21.04? Thank you.

Comment: Why you do not want  to use `cd ~/Downloads/ubundu\ 21.04 ; wget https://releases.ubuntu.com/hirsute/SHA256SUMS ; sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS` ?

Comment: I did and got 2 warnings.. 


Saving to: ‘SHA256SUMS.1’

SHA256SUMS.1        100%[===================>]     198  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2021-09-04 12:27:38 (4,91 MB/s) - ‘SHA256SUMS.1’ saved [198/198]

sha256sum: ubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso: No such file or directory
ubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso: FAILED open or read
sha256sum: ubuntu-21.04-live-server-amd64.iso: No such file or directory
ubuntu-21.04-live-server-amd64.iso: FAILED open or read
sha256sum: WARNING: 2 listed files could not be read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are unable to find the location of the iso from the command line, I would suggest you check it with a GUI program.

Install `gtkhash` with the command

```
sudo apt install gtkhash
```

[image: gtkhash]

Select the .iso file in `gtkhash`, and generate the SHA256 sum.

Copy the given SHA256 hash in the `Check` textbox, and the software would show a checkmark if they match.

Afterwards, follow the official tutorials for creating a [bootable live USB](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview), and using it to [install Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. did all of it. GTKhash confirmed 2 checkmarks and both match. How it helps me to install ubuntu?

Comment: @iirniak It means that the iso is not corrupt, and it can be used to install Ubuntu. Now you have to create a live USB and boot it to install Ubuntu (there are excellent tutorials, just search for it).

Comment: I just learned that my machine is  i386 architecture and Ubuntu will not support this architecture. I guess it is a reason I am not able to download Ubuntu 21.04. Any suggestions on what I can update my machine too? Doesn't have to be ubuntu. Can do any linux operational system, as long as it is newest

Comment: which newest Linux operational system I can install on  i386 architecture laptop?

Comment: @iirinak I suggest you go with Debian XFCE edition. https://www.debian.org/ Here is the download link for ISO. https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/i386/iso-hybrid/debian-live-11.0.0-i386-xfce.iso Here is the download link for torrent of the same https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/i386/bt-hybrid/debian-live-11.0.0-i386-xfce.iso.torrent By the way, how much RAM do you have?

Comment: Archisman, seem I have 1609148 RAM, if I am reading correct. > "me@me:~$ $ free
$: command not found
me@me:~$ free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        8122548     1609148     4198788      460124     2314612     5392872
Swap:       2097148           0     2097148". So I have to create live USB on Ubuntu 21.04?

Comment: @iirinak Yes, you have to create a live USB, and boot with it. Just search in your favorite search engine something like "how to create a live USB in Ubuntu"

Comment: Thank you Archisman. I just learn that my laptop can run on both, I386 and I689. So I can still get Ubuntu 21.04. do I have to format USB stick to particular format? But I would love to try Debian XFCE edition. Thank you very much for your guidance. If I have trouble with installation live USB, can I email you directly plz?

Comment: @iirinak You can also try Xubuntu, which is XFCE edition of Ubuntu (in general, Ubuntu is slightly more user friendly than Debian). But with 16 GB ram, even regular Ubuntu would work very well. I have edited my answer with link for live USB and installation. You can ask a new question or comment here if you face any problem. If the problem persists, I would share my email.

Comment: @iirinak By the way, it would be a good idea to perform a fresh install of 21.04 rather than an "upgrade install", because the "upgrade" can lead to installation of a lot of unnecessary packages which were necessary in 18.04, but are not anymore required in 21.04.

Comment: Thank you all for your kind contribution. Was able to re-install f21.04 rom bootable usb.